# "Unkown (custom) loss function" when using tflite_convert on a {TF 2.0.0-beta1 ; Keras} model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

## Summary

My question is composed by:

- A context in which I present my project, my working environment and my workflow
- The detailed problem
- The concerned parts of my  code
- The solutions I tried to solve my problem
- The question reminder

## Context

I've written a Python Keras implementation of a downgraded version of the original Super-Resolution GAN. Now I want to test it using Google Firebase Machine Learning Kit, by hosting it in the Google servers. That's why I have to convert my Keras program to a TensorFlow Lite one.

### Environment and workflow (with the problem)

I'm training my program on Google Colab working environment: there, I've installed `TF 2.0.0-beta1` (this choice is motivated by this uncorrect answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/57408/78409).

Workflow (and problem):

1. I write locally my Python Keras program, keeping in mind that it will run on TF 2. So I use TF 2 imports, for example: `from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam` and also `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization`
2. I send my code to my Drive
3. I run without any problem my Google Colab Notebook: TF 2 is used.
4. I get the output model in my Drive, and I download it.
5. I try to convert this model to the TFLite format by executing the following CLI: `tflite_convert --output_file=srgan.tflite --keras_model_file=srgan.h5`: **here the problem appears**.

## The problem

Instead of outputing the TF Lite converted model from the TF (Keras) model, the previous CLI outputs this error:

> ValueError: Unknown loss function:build_vgg19_loss_network

The function `build_vgg19_loss_network` is a custom loss function that I've implemented and that must be used by the GAN.

## Parts of code that rise this problem

### Presenting the custom loss function

The custom loss function is implemented like that:

```
def build_vgg19_loss_network(ground_truth_image, predicted_image):
    loss_model = Vgg19Loss.define_loss_model(high_resolution_shape)
    return mean(square(loss_model(ground_truth_image) - loss_model(predicted_image)))
```

### Compiling the generator network with my custom loss function

`generator_model.compile(optimizer=the_optimizer, loss=build_vgg19_loss_network)`

## What I've tried to do in order to solve the problem

1. As I read it on StackOverflow (link at the beginning of this question), TF 2 was thought to be sufficient to output a Keras model which would be correctly processed by my `tflite_convert` CLI. But it's not, obviously.
2. As I read it on GitHub, I tried to manually set my custom loss function among Keras' loss functions, by adding these lines: `import tensorflow.keras.losses
   tensorflow.keras.losses.build_vgg19_loss_network = build_vgg19_loss_network`. It didn't work.
3. I read on GitHub I could use custom objects with `load_model` Keras function: but I only want to use `compile` Keras function. Not `load_model`.

## My final question

I want to do only minor changes to my code, since it works fine. So I don't want, for example, to replace `compile` with `load_model`. With this constraint, could you help me, please, to make my CLI `tflite_convert` works with my custom loss function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are claiming that TFLite conversion is failing due to a custom loss function, you can save the model file without keep the optimizer details. To do that, set `include_optimizer` parameter to False as shown below:

```
model.save('model.h5', include_optimizer=False)
```

Now, if all the layers inside your model are convertible, they should get converted into TFLite file.

Edit: 
You can then convert the h5 file like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')   # srgan.h5 for you
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Usual practice to overcome the unsupported operators in TFLite conversion is [documented here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom).

Comment: I have tested your solution still using Google Colab and downloaded the model from Google's Drive. I used the CLI TFLiteConvert. But there is a pb. If I don't include the optimizer, TFLiteConvert says: "No training configuration found in save file: the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually." - so locally my machine must compile the model by itself. It'd take months and months (I have only a poor CPU - that's why I use Google Colab). So your answer worked but it rises this new problem.

Comment: Why don't you load the weights from your pb file into your network, then save the model either in h5 or saved_model format using the API I have shown in the answer. You can then convert your h5 or saved_model format into TFLite using this Python API itself: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_savedmodel_

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Your comment seems to give birth to a new answer (which uses the API part of your current answer). Could you, please, create a new answer (I will upvote it), clearly explaining these different steps? ///// By the way, to be sure I am rightly understood: for now what I have is my .H5 model, which I had thanks to `model.save('model.h5', include_optimizer=False)` (cf. your answer). But when I use `tflite_convert`, it naturally rises this (new) error: `No training configuration found in save file: the model was not compiled. Compile it manually.`.

Comment: Any idea you have?:)

Comment: Can you tell me the name of error? I think it is a warning you are getting. Can you check in your directory whether tflite file is created or not? If not, please can you upload your h5 file somewhere and share the link so that it can be inspected

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. This isn't an error indeed, but a warning. The tflite file is not created: indeed, I keyboard interrupt the `tflite_convert` process because it's going to compile the model on my own machine which just has a poor CPU: it'd take months and months. Yes you can find my H5 file here so that you can inspect it: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1dc5deaec34bd3092983e1b97ee4a88b20190822081148/350400 .

Comment: A bounty of +50rep is available from now ;)

Comment: I have edited the code to convert the h5 file. Your h5 file is getting converted with the above code. I can upload the tflite file for you if you want it.

Comment: This is the link to download it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/erx1xq7np8axffw/converted_model.tflite?dl=0  I was not able to convert it in CPU. I made use of free GPU available in Google Colab.

Comment: Just adding that "optimizer" and "compiling" are not necessary for using the model at all. The only role of the optimizer is "training". If the model is already trained and you are not training it anymore, you don't need the optimizer or the loss.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have a question: since I've output the `h5` file using Colab, `model.save('model.h5', include_optimizer=False)` being written, why couldn't I output the `.tflite` version using the CLI `tflite_convert`? (indeed, the warning `No training configuration found in save file: the model was not compiled. Compile it manually.` was shown). You have succeeded in outputing the `.tflite` version thanks to some Python code, but not using the CLI.

Comment: I think the CLI and your Python code are actually the same, but that you used the Python code instead in order to be able to run it on Colab. (?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I recommend changing the loss to "mse" since you already have a well-trained model and you don't need to train with the .tflite file.